# Does a transformer have different primary and secondary PFs?

Tags: capacitor, transformer, ac, power-factor-correction

I tried connecting two energy meters on primary and secondary and found that they were showing different values when a load was connected to the transformer.

Does a transformer have two different PFs, one for primary and another for secondary? If yes, how to calculate and fix them?

Comment: The transformer has losses and it's as simple as that. That's what gives you different readings.

Comment: @Andyaka so transformer has only one PF that is at primary, correct?

Comment: It's power factor is load dependent mainly so, no.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal transformer will show equal PF, P and VA, and V and I when accounting for turns ratio.  A nonideal transformer contributes shunt (magnetizing) and series (leakage) inductance, and other effects which may be relevant to harmonics or noise.  Not to mention losses, which increase real power on the primary side.  How this affects PF depends on load, but in general PF can differ.

Aside, ChatGPT isn't an informative resource: it won't tell you anything that isn't in the training set, which is to say, what's on much of the internet.  It generally won't tell you anything that's not accessible via Google already.  It's very capable in natural language, but that's it; it has no ability for inference or extrapolation, and is not specialized in technical subjects.